# How can I merge multiple sets of morphological components (perhaps selected using different metrics)?

Tags: image-processing

Let's say I use `SelectComponents` to select morphological components in an image according to some criterion, like "Elongation".  Then let's say, I pull out a different set of morphological components using another criterion like "Area".

```
m1 = SelectComponents[testImage, "Elongation", # == 1 &];
m2 = SelectComponents[testImage, "Area", # > 42 &];
```

How can I properly merge `m1` and `m2` into a single set of non-intersecting morphological components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine the outputs of `SelectComponents` in a straightforward way. Let's take a test image from the docs:

```
c=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSXIj.png"]
```

[image]

and select two conditions on the components:

```
m1 = SelectComponents[c, "Elongation", # > 0.5 &];
m2 = SelectComponents[c, "Area", # < 1000 &];
```

These `m1` and `m2` are binary images with 1's where the criterion is fulfilled and 0's where it fails.

```
{m1,m2}
```

[image]

You can find the intersection of the two components by multiplying

```
ImageMultiply[m1,m2]
```

[image]

You can find the union of the two selected components by adding (for binary images, `ImageAdd` is essentially the logical OR of the two images)

```
ImageAdd[m1, m2]
```

[image]

Comment: _I think_ the OP is referring to a _Union_ operation, while you're addressing an _Intersection_. Not sure, though

Comment: @belisarius -- I've added the union operation.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Mathematica documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SelectComponents.html):

> Selecting components based on multiple properties:
>
> `SelectComponents[image, {"Count", "AdjacentBorderCount"}, #1 > 100 && #2 == 0 &]`

So instead of calling SelectComponents twice and somehow merge the output, you can just call it once with any logical combination of your criteria.

Comment: Out of curiosity, there isn't anything like ComponentJoin[{m1, m2, ...}]?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you could always add the two images, binarize the result and use MorphologicalComponents to implement that.

Comment: Can probably be done with `ArrayComponents` and `ComponentMeasurements[image,"Label",-1]`