# Why is the SelectComponents behaving differently?

Tags: image-processing, image3d, segmentation

based on the code provided by Dr. belisarius at [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35327/selecting-morphological-components-by-clicking-on-them?rq=1), I wanted to test it on a single slice of a 3d image. If I write the code in the following way I get the desired output.

```
i2 = Image3DSlices[im];
k2 = Image[MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate[i2[[6]]], 0.9]];
DynamicModule[{pts2 = {{-1, 1}/2}}, {LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts2], 
Image[k2, ImageSize -> 300], LocatorAutoCreate -> True, 
Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 10]], 
Dynamic@SelectComponents[k2, "Label", 
MemberQ[PixelValue[k2, #] & /@ Round@pts2, 1. #] &]}]
```

But when I try the same thing with the following modification, it's not working properly. It selects only a specific segment, no matter which segment region is clicked.

```
k3 = Image3D[MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate[im], 0.9]]
i1 = Image3DSlices[k3];
k1 = Image[i1[[6]]];
DynamicModule[{pts1 = {{-1, 1}/2}}, {LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts1], 
Image[k1, ImageSize -> 300], LocatorAutoCreate -> True, 
Appearance -> Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 10]], 
Dynamic@SelectComponents[k1, "Label", 
MemberQ[PixelValue[k1, #] & /@ Round@pts1, 1. #] &]}]
```

Comment: The first block of code does not work either; `im` is undefined.

Comment: im is a sample 3D image. You have define it first.

Comment: I encourage you to do so.